# please tell me how to export fbx animation from this model

Tags: animation, export, .fbx

reply please with detail , I hope it is easy for all

[image: tell me how to export it with fbx animation]

Comment: with fbx it's hard, fbx can't do it... try alembic (.abc)
File / Export / Alembic(.abc)

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but I did find this tutorial if you're using Unity, https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.formats.alembic@1.0/manual/tutorial.html Also, I found a video that further elaborates, download the package in the description.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChZWVCgMWyU Hope you're using Unity, I only found this because I'm trying to do the same thing with my character's hair.

Comment: kindly say how to export that model in .FBX     cause fbx runs smoothly in my game engine   replay ....must

Answer (score 0):

FBX can't do it directly... try alembic (.abc)
File / Export / Alembic(.abc)

And I find a way to export his modifier animation in fbx

One time you have the modifier animation export it as .mmd: 
   File/Export/LightwavePointCache(.mdd) (".mdd is an addon you need to turn it on")

Them export it again as .obj: File/Export/Wavefront(.obj)

Next in a clean scene or in the same or in other layer, just to keep easy read:
import the obj ocean.obj

Select the ocean.obj and import the ocean.mdd

"if if works know you have the animations as a sequence of Shape Keys"

So the last step is to export it as .fbx
File/Export/FBX
I turn Custom Properties on

I do it base on this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7oistIgo1U